# Driving a WS2815 12V LED strip with a CC+CV driver

Tags: power-supply, led-driver, constant-current, constant-power

I am selecting a driver/PSU to power a string of **WS2815 12V LEDs**.

> WS2815 datasheet here:
>   http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/138

One option I am looking at to power these strips is the **Mean Well HLG-320H-12**.

> HLG-320H-12 datasheet here:
>   https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/HLG-320H/HLG-320H-spec.pdf

But, this is a Constant Voltage + Constant Current LED driver.

My question is: **will this work?**

The WS2815 is digitally dimmable through its data channel (same as the rest of the WS281x family / WS2811, WS2812, WS2813). I have no need for dimming from the PSU side.

I usually power these type of LEDs through a Constant Voltage PSU, but I need more amps than (e.g.) the Mean Well LPV series can offer. Then I found the HLG-320H-12, which suits my Amp-needs, but I'm not sure if CC+CV would work with this strip.

Comment: No, you drive these with a fixed DC voltage of 12V nominal (absolute maximum range of 9.5V to 13.5V as per the datasheet).

Comment: Yes, the Meanwell supply will work for you. You would set the CC limit beyond the current requirements of your strip(s) and would therefore act just as a constant voltage supply. For example if you have WS2815's with a total load current of 20A and the CC limit is set to 22A, the supply will simply deliver the required current at the voltage set. That voltage can be adjusted from 10.8 - 13.5V ...I'd suggest you set it to 10.8V to minimize the power dissipated in the WS2813's.